# Insert and rotate in AVL tree

Tags: java, tree

I have the following insert method for inserting into an AVL tree.

```
if(node == null){
        node = new AVLTreeNode(key);  
    }
    else if (key == node.getKey()){
        //do nothing, duplicate key
    }
    else if (key<node.getKey()){
        node.setLeft(insert(node.getLeft(), key));
        if(node.getBalanceFactor() == 2){

            if(key< node.getLeft().getKey()){
                node = rotateWithLeftChild(node);
            }
            else{
                node = doubleRotateWithLeftChild(node);
            }
        }  
    }
    else {
        node.setRight(insert(node.getRight(), key));
        if(node.getBalanceFactor() == -2){

            if(key> node.getRight().getKey()){
            node = rotateWithRightChild(node);
            }
            else{
            node = doubleRotateWithRightChild(node);
            }
        }  

    }

    //set node height to max children+1

    if(node.hasLeft() && node.hasRight()){
    node.setHeight(Math.max(node.getLeft().getHeight(), node.getRight().getHeight())+1);
    }
    else if(node.hasLeft() && node.hasRight() == false){
        node.setHeight(node.getLeft().getHeight()+1);
    }
    else if(node.hasRight() && node.hasLeft() == false){
        node.setHeight(node.getRight().getHeight()+1);
    }
    else{
        node.setHeight(1);
    }

   return node;
```

and then I have the rotate right method that looks like this:

```
public static AVLTreeNode rotateWithRightChild( AVLTreeNode k1 )
{
AVLTreeNode k2 = k1.getRight();
    k1.setRight(k2.getLeft());
    k2.setLeft(k1);
    k1.setHeight(Math.max(k1.getLeft().getHeight(), 0)+1);
    k2.setHeight(Math.max(k2.getRight().getHeight(), k1.getHeight())+1);

    return k2;
}
```

However the if I insert 1 then 2 then 3, I get an error because I  have a Null Pointer, it seems the rotate method is working on the last node with key 3 rather than its parent, so im not sure how to fix this as there is no getParent() method provided in the framework. Any suggestions?

Comment: It would help if you highlight for us which line has the null-pointer.  I'm guessing it's the k1.setHeight call - yes??    Because, looking at it, If you insert 1, then 2, then 3, then without running the code I reckon you'll have top node = 1, top.right=2, top.right.right=3 before rotation (and all the ".left" references will be null).  This means when rotateWithRightChild is called, k1 will be the top node, so k1.getLeft() will be null.  Solution would be to check for this, and have a default Height for this situation (I guess 1).

Comment: Ya, that is the correct line where the null pointer is giving an error, let me try this